# How to get page number in dynamic report?

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

like page number=1,page number=2 ans so on,is there any pre defined attribute for that in dynamic report API,I know the question is too dumb,but still i could not find an answer to this question even through google,pls help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add page no to your report you need to add this line to your report object

```
try {
        report()//create new report design
          .columns(...) //adds columns

          .pageFooter(cmp.pageXofY()) //shows number of page at page footer

          .show() //shows report
          .print() //prints report
          ...
      } catch (DRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
      }
```